# Transpose image dimensions

Tags: python, image, dimensions

Hy! Is there a solution for changing the (width, height, channel) dimensions of an image to (channel, height, width) in Python?

For example:
`224 x 224 x 3 -> 3 x 224 x 224`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.transpose` https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html:

```
new_image = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the image is represented as a `nd.array` you can use `moveaxis` method like the following:

```
x = np.zeros((3, 4, 5))
np.moveaxis(x, 0, -1).shape
# (4, 5, 3)
np.moveaxis(x, -1, 0).shape
# (5, 3, 4)
```

And in your specific case:

```
x = np.zeros((224, 224, 3))
np.moveaxis(x, (2, 0, 1), (0, 1, 2)).shape
# (3, 224, 224)
```

You can read about the method in the following link:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html

Comment: I actually load an image with OpenCV and I tried both of moveaxis, without any succes :?

Comment: @Fellon Can you add you attempts to the question?